# AutoFeat: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am currently using [AutoFeat](https://github.com/cod3licious/autofeat) as a tool to generate new features and select the best ones.

```py
"""
Args:
    features (np.array): features as a structured numpy array
    targetFeature (np.array): target features
"""

autoFeatRegressor = AutoFeatRegressor(verbose=verbose, feateng_steps=3)
newFeatureDf = autoFeatRegressor.fit_transform(features, targetFeature)
```

The `fit_transform` function is throwing an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autofeat\featsel.py in _select_features_1run(df, target, problem_type, verbose)
    112         try:
--> 113             model.fit(df, target)
    114         except ValueError:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_least_angle.py in fit(self, X, y)
   1672 
-> 1673         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, y_numeric=True)
   1674         X = as_float_array(X, copy=self.copy_X)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    580             else:
--> 581                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    582             out = X, y

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    963 
--> 964     X = check_array(
    965         X,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    799         if force_all_finite:
--> 800             _assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")
    801 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
    113             type_err = "infinity" if allow_nan else "NaN, infinity"
--> 114             raise ValueError(
    115                 msg_err.format(

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')
```

Below are the logs of AutoFeatRegressor:

```
[AutoFeat] The 3 step feature engineering process could generate up to 118923 features.
[AutoFeat] With 124 data points this new feature matrix would use about 0.06 gb of space.
[feateng] Step 1: transformation of original features
[feateng] Generated 60 transformed features from 14 original features - done.
[feateng] Step 2: first combination of features
[feateng]               0/           2701 feature tuples combined
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2691: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  c /= stddev[:, None]
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2692: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  c /= stddev[None, :]
[feateng] Generated 10011 feature combinations from 2701 original feature tuples - done.
[feateng] Step 3: transformation of new features
[feateng] Generated 43956 transformed features from 10011 original features - done.
[feateng] Generated altogether 58331 new features in 3 steps
[feateng] Removing correlated features, as well as additions at the highest level
[feateng] Generated a total of 14481 additional features
[featsel] Scaling data...done.
[featsel] Feature selection run 1/5
```

This is what I tried so far:

1. I tested both `features` & `targetFeature` for nan & infinity. All values are fine.
2. My values are float64. Converted them to float32. Faced same issue.
3. Tried using `FeatureSelector` to check if there is anything wrong with my data structure. It worked perfectly
4. I tried passing `features` as a numpy array and pandas Dataframe (they say in docs that both are supported). Both didn't work.

Edit #1: link to [Github Issue](https://github.com/cod3licious/autofeat/issues/32) (I created it)

Edit #2: reduced the number of features. It worked. I guess the automatically generated features are causing this issue. Will investigate further.

Edit #3: found the feature that was causing the bug. It was a list of numbers with the same values. It seems with the transformations that the library does automatically lead to nan/infinity values which eventually lead to issues.

Comment: How did you test them for nan & infinity?  Did you use `np.isnan(x).any()` and `np.isfinite(x).all()`?

Comment: @Tim Roberts Both. np.isnan(x).any() gives False. np.isfinite(x).all() gives True.

Comment: My next step would be to call `sklearn.util.check_X_y` directly and see what it says.

Comment: It returned 2 numpy arrays without any exceptions.

Comment: And you passed `y_numeric=True` to that, as the traceback shows?  Doesn't make sense. 
 The arrays are passed directly through, so `X` and `y` should be exactly `features` and `targetFeatures`.  If `sklearn.util.check_X_y( features, targetFeatures )` doesn't fail, then passing them to `fit_transform` can't fail.

Comment: This is my code:
import sklearn.utils as skutils
skutils.check_X_y(features, targetFeatures, y_numeric=True).

Comment: @TimRoberts would it be possible new features generated by autofeat lead to this?

Comment: @TimRoberts Added edit#2

Comment: @TimRoberts most probably found the issue. Added Edit#3